# What is the correct way to define functions to use in a rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If one of my model functions does something complex or its logic has some part that can be reused in another model function, is it correct to define a third function inside the model so that it becomes an instance method or define it as a class method?

My first solution was to do something like this in my model file(say user.rb):

```
#Some Function
def magic_function
  return true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def first_function
    return magic_function
  end

  def second_function
    return 1 if magic_function
    return 0
  end
end
```

but I can't stub the magic_function while doing rspec tests and browsing through the internet makes me believe that what I did is not usually done by others... Some seem to use modules but in my case, this function is only needed within this file. I just defined it to DRY my code out or to make it more readable but I don't think it should be an instance method as I don't need to call it from outside this file, neither does it need to be a class method for the same reason.
Where is the right place to define a function like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s hard to say without knowing what `magic_function` does, but it seems you want it to be [private](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-private):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def first_function
    return magic_function
  end

  def second_function
    return 1 if magic_function
    return 0
  end

  private

  def magic_function
    return true
  end
end
```

This will allow you to call `magic_function` from other instance methods of User, but it cannot be called from outside it:

```
user = User.new
user.first_function  # works
user.magic_function  # NoMethodError: private method `magic_function' called
```

Note, however, that you should still not stub `magic_function` simply because you should never stub the [system under test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_under_test). It should be tested implicitly through the public methods. If you want to test it separately, you should put it in a new Class or Module and call out to it from User.

Comment: That's great. Thanks.
About stubbing. I was trying to make unit tests and as I understand each test should address one function at a time so if I don't stub this function, that would break that rule. Also, some of these magic functions perform calls to other services(APIs), I have to stub them in this case, right?

Comment: @AhmedFathy You should not stub methods on the object you’re testing. Not stubbing a method within the object does not violate the rule. You can still stub out services since they’re in different objects.

Comment: But if I don't stub this function and it turned out to be problematic and gave some error, it would cause tests to all functions that use it fail too although these functions don't have a problem but they're failing because this one has. I'm not saying you're wrong, I just don't know if this was the purpose of the rule or not. Is it correct to still not stub it knowing that it might cause tests to other functions fail when these functions are correct?

Comment: @AhmedFathy Except it doesn’t matter if it fails since nothing outside the class can ever call it. It only matters if the methods that use it fail.